# Hosts configuration on home wireless router

Tags: networking, router, console, telnet, hosts

I have a home network working via a ADSL Wireless Router (Sagem F@st 2804).

Also, I have a web server working on my pc and some virtual hosts on it. I want to make those hosts to be accesable via the whole home network, not only on my pc.

I was trying to find a configuration options for this in router web interface, but there is nothing related to HOST->IP configuration.

So now I've connected to the router via telnet. The question is: how to configure "hosts" via telnet on my router? I don't have a lot experience with console commands.

The thing I want is that if I go devsite.loc on my ipad it goes to 192.168.1.100

Update:
These commands I have via telnet connection
[telnet console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxfIr.png)

Maybe there is another way to connect to the router?

Comment: "Is there another way to connect to the router?"  This depends on the router, but you never told us the exact model number of the router?  Did you want us to guess?

Comment: sagem f@st 2804

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the router you are using. Check under the DNS tab in your router's configuration page. If you can telnet into the router, check if it has vi or pico installed and edit /etc/hosts.

Comment: as I said that it has not DNS configuration related to HOST<->IP